# Как сделать слой полупрозрачным в ie7, ie8?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Как сделать слой полупрозрачным в ie7, ie8?
В слое содержится png картинка на всю его ширину и высоту.

Answer (score 3):

```
.opacity_block{
    filter: alpha(Opacity=50); /* значение своё установите */
    zoom: 1;
}
```

**UPD**: Комплексное решение, включая IE7,8

```
/* Для ослов < 8 */
.opacity_block {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #900;
    filter: alpha(Opacity=50);
    zoom: 1;
    z-index: expression(runtimeStyle.zIndex = 1, this.innerHTML = "100500" + this.innerHTML);
}
/* для нормальных браузеров и некоторых ослов */
.opacity_block:before {
    content: '100500';
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #900;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(Opacity=50);
}
```

Comment: У меня прозрачность нужна для псевдоэлемента :before, показанный пример не помогает, все остается как было. Может быть для псевдоэлементов не работает? Картинка, что в заднем фоне похожа на радиальный градиент - типа сияние. Ее нужно сделать более тусклой и прозрачной. В обычных браузерах так и происходит, но фильтер для ие не помогает.

Comment: IE7 не понимает псевдоэлемент [:before](http://htmlbook.ru/css/before).

Comment: Но эффекта не было IE8, в итоге я сделала полупрозрачность через фильтр градиента, где можно задать прозрачность. Этот способ описан в книге Сила css3, я специально поискала в ней упоминание про фильтр opacity, но не нашла его. Автор изначально использовал для полупрозрачности именно градиент и даже не пытался alpha opacity, интересно. почему?

Comment: Эту книгу не читал, поэтому ничего сказать не могу. Свой вариант проверил - работает везьде (*только изначально забыл сюда добавить opacity... исправил*)